# Jquery deferred call back oddness

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-deferred

I was playing around with call backs and deferred functions in jQuery and was wondering if anyone could tell me why this works

http://jsfiddle.net/austinbv/QVujr/

```
  get_each_total = function(callback) {
    var requests;
    requests = [];
      var url;
        url = "http://otter.topsy.com/search.js?callback=?&apikey=38A260E9D12A4908B1AF9184B691131&q=justin+bieber&window=d";
        return requests.push($.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        }));
    return $.when.apply($, requests).then(function() {
      callback();
    }, function() {
      return alert("There was an error communicating with a remote library, try again in a few");
    });
  };



  get_each_total_broken = function(callback) {
    var requests;
    requests = [];
      var url;
        url = "http://otter.topsy.com/hjhkl/sehjkhhkjhkarch.js?callback=?&apikey=38A260E9D12A4908B1AF9184B691131&q=justin+bieber&window=d";
        return requests.push($.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        }));
    return $.when.apply($, requests).then(function() {
      callback();
    }, function() {
      return alert("There was an error communicating with a remote library, try again in a few");
    });
  };

$(function () {
    get_each_total(alert("success"));
    get_each_total_broken(alert("fail"));
});
```

and this does not

http://jsfiddle.net/austinbv/wzve6/

```
  get_each_total = function(callback) {
    var requests;
    requests = [];
      var url;
        url = "http://otter.topsy.com/search.js?callback=?&apikey=38A260E9D12A4908B1AF9184B691131&q=justin+bieber&window=d";
        return requests.push($.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        }));
    return $.when.apply($, requests).then(function() {
      callback();
    }, function() {
      return alert("There was an error communicating with a remote library, try again in a few");
    });
  };



  get_each_total_broken = function(callback) {
    var requests;
    requests = [];
      var url;
        url = "http://otter.topsy.com/hjhkl/sehjkhhkjhkarch.js?callback=?&apikey=38A260E9D12A4908B1AF9184B691131&q=justin+bieber&window=d";
        return requests.push($.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        }));
    return $.when.apply($, requests).then(function() {
      callback();
    }, function() {
      return alert("There was an error communicating with a remote library, try again in a few");
    });
  };

$(function () {
    get_each_total(function () { alert("success")});
    get_each_total_broken(function () {alert("fail")});
});
```

as you can see the only difference is in the last two lines, where an anonymous function wraps the callback.  Any insight would be nice.

Comment: I think you pasted the same code twice.

Comment: @matt nope take a look at the last 4 lines in each code

Comment: For future questions, please post the methods that are identical only once. This will keep us from having to scan and compare them before we can tell you what's causing your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This piece of code:

```
return requests.push($.getJSON(url, function(data) {
}));
```

exits out of your function. The `callback` is never called.

P.S. When you're saying `the only difference is an anonymous function wrapping the callback`, you imply that you're also passing a function in the first version of your code. That is not true; you're trying to pass in whatever `alert('whatever');` is returning, which is *`undefined`*!

**Further explanation:**

Both of your functions (`get_each_total`, & `get_each_total_broken`) expect the parameter to be a function. This is evident by you trying to call it as a function later on in your code (`callback()`). However, this line:

```
get_each_total(alert("success"));
```

does not pass a function to `get_each_total`. It is equivalent to the following:

```
var returnedFromAlert = alert("success");
get_each_total(returnedFromAlert);
```

So, basically, you're not passing anything into your `get_each_total` function. You get a `success` alert *right away, before `get_each_total` has been called.*

Comment: Can you elaborate on your last paragraph

Comment: I see what you are saying http://cl.ly/0h2L0J2t0X0s2U090201 < proof of concept, but why would the one wrapped in an anonymous function not run then? I tried removing the returns and success seems to run but the failure does not http://jsfiddle.net/austinbv/wzve6/2/

Comment: @austinbv: Why are you using `$.getJSON` on a service that returns JSONP?

Comment: Yeah I know I did it for the example, adding a callback=? with $.getJSON, has jQuery do some magic and run the wrapping function, so why not use $.getJSON

Answer (score 2):

```
get_each_total(function () { alert("success")});
```

here you have the `function (){ alert ....` that returns a function object

```
 get_each_total(alert("success"));
```

here `alert("success")` is an object of whatever type `alert()` returns and it is not a function.

**Edit:-** in respone to the comment i'm going to further clarify.

when the browser sees

```
do_something(is_it_complete(arg1, arg2));
```

it goes throught the following steps:

1. Get the function `is_it_complete` and call it arguments `arg1` and `arg2`.
2. get the function `do_something` and call it with the result of the above as an argument.

When the browser sees:

```
do_something(function () { is_it_complete(arg1, arg2) });
```

it does:

1. Create a function object that calls `is_it_complete(arg1, arg2)`
2. Get the function `do_something` and call it with the above object as an argument.

**Edit 3:-** Ok so in the first one it called the alert before running your code so it appeared to work.

you have:

```
get_each_total = function(callback) {
     // ... *snip* 
    return requests.push($.getJSON(url, function(data) {}));
    return $.when.apply($, requests).then(function() {
        // ... *snip*
    });
};
```

the second return is never reached.

**Edit:-** thought i would put a few tips after reading the code:

```
var requests;
requests = [];
```

is redundant change that style to

```
var requests = [];
var url = " ....";
```

When you do not pass any arguments to a callback do no wrap it.

```
.then(function(){ callback();})
```

it is the same as:

```
.then(callback);
```

and as mentioned in the comments your url

```
url = "http://otter.topsy.com/hjhkl/sehjkhhkjhkarch.js?callback=?&apikey=38A260E9D12A4908B1AF9184B691131&q=justin+bieber&window=d";
```

Should be

```
url = "http://otter.topsy.com/hjhkl/sehjkhhkjhkarch.js?callback=somevalue&apikey=38A260E9D12A4908B1AF9184B691131&q=justin+bieber&window=d";
```

or even:

```
url = "http://otter.topsy.com/hjhkl/sehjkhhkjhkarch.js"
$.getJSON(url, {
    "callback": "somevalue",
    "apikey": "38A260E9D12A4908B1AF9184B691131",
    "q": "justin bieber",
    "window": "d"
}, function(data){ alert("Got: " + data);});
```

Comment: So why can you not wrap the callback in an anonymous function, shouldn't the way that code is built run the call back after the deferrers complete?

Comment: you **must** wrap the code in a function. `function(){ ... }` is an object of type function. `alert()` means get me the result of this function. I'll add more to explain the situation.

Comment: Then why when wrapped are the alerts never called

Comment: Ahh... If you hit the "tidy up" button in jsfiddle you will see the problem: you have `return requests.push( ...` and the next line is `return $.when.apply( ...`

Comment: @austinbv you have `.js?callback=?&` replace the second `?` with something (eg. `.js?callback=n&`)

Answer (score 1):

Neither example works.  (Hint to reviewers: it is the last two lines of which he speaks.)

In your first example, you call `alert()`, which raises the alert dialog, *even before the `get_each_total()` function is called.*  Javascript invokes it, showing the alert (and giving the illusion than something happened), and passes the result of the `alert()` call to `get_each_total()` (and does the same with the alert in the following function, too).  The result is null.  If the callback were ever called, this would raise an error.

In the second example, you're declaring a function and passing a reference to it to `get_each_total()`, which can then be called via your `callback()` expression.  A function is something that responds to the `()` operator, meaning "do this."  It would actually do something (show the alert) if your code succeeded.

But your code does not.  Going to the fiddle, and looking at the console, I see this message: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)."  `getJSON()` never triggers the callback because *it never succeeds*.

[EDIT] @austinbv pointed out to me that I'd missed something.  The 500 code is a deliberate test on his part.  But his code is still broken in `get_each_total_broken()`; there is a misplaced `return` in the line

```
return requests.push($.getJSON(url, function(data) {  }));
```

This returns immediately from `get_each_total_broken`.  The `when().then()` clause is never invoked, so he never sees the error handling.  The immediacy of the alerts in the first example continues to give the illusion that something happened.

Comment: That is the point of the deferred fail, If you look at how the getJSON's work they are passed as a promise to the $.when() and then $.then() handles them.  Both are called, the 500 error calls the failed callback. while the successful call to topsy's api calls triggers the success call back. Set up some break points in your console and you will see :)

Comment: My point is that the alerts() in the first aren't callbacks, and cannot work.   And I just noticed, in your second example, there's a `return` call in the line `requests.push` that returns the results of `requests.push` and never gets to your `when().then()` clause, so that why that doesn't work.

Comment: Take a look at my comments on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278511/jquery-deferred-call-back-oddness/7278589#7278589 You will see even with the returns removed the fail callback is never called

Comment: +1 this is the correct answer and it also seems you found it 9 mins before I did. Good one!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with your code:

1) In the last two lines of code: The first example is passing the result of an execution of the "alert" method to both the "get_each_total" and "get_each_total_broken" methods. The second example is passing a function that when executed will call "alert". The second example is the correct method to perform.

For Example:

```
function test(v) {
    // do something
    return null;
}

// executes "test" immediately and passes it's result to "someOtherFunction"
someOtherFunction(test(v));
// will pass a function to "someOtherFunction" to be executed later
someOtherFunction(function(){ test("value"); });
```

2) You have 2 "return" statements in both your methods. The first "return" encountered within a method will return it's value and exit the method; thus resulting in the second "return" statement to never be executed. Consiquentially, the call to "$.when.apply" in both methods will never, ever get executed.

Comment: If you look at http://jsfiddle.net/austinbv/wzve6/2/ I have removed the returns and still the failed for $.then is never run

Comment: Part 1 of my answer still answers your question. I revised it with a code example to make it more clear.

Comment: then why does't it run in the fiddle in my first comment