# Deferred failed callback not calling

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred, jquery-callback

I am trying to figure out why the failed callback is not working for this deferred

http://jsfiddle.net/austinbv/wzve6/6/

```
get_each_total = function(callback) {
    var requests;
    requests = [];
    var url;
    url = "http://otter.topsy.com/search.js?callback=?&apikey=38A260E9D12A4908B1AF9184B691131&q=justin+bieber&window=d";
    requests.push($.getJSON(url, function(data) {}));
    $.when.apply($, requests).then(function() {
        callback();
    }, function() {
        alert("There was an error communicating with a remote library, try again in a few");
    });
};

get_each_total_broken = function(callback) {
    var requests;
    requests = [];
    var url;
    url = "http://otter.topsy.com/hjhkl/sehjkhhkjhkarch.js?callback=?&apikey=38A260E9D12A4908B1AF9184B691131&q=justin+bieber&window=d";
    requests.push($.getJSON(url));
    $.when.apply($, requests).then(function() {
        callback();
    }, function() {
        callback();
    });
};

$(function() {
    get_each_total_broken(function() {
        alert("fail");
    });
});
```

I had a question [Jquery deferred call back oddness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278511/jquery-deferred-call-back-oddness/7278633) that is similar but I figured this is different enough it should have it's own.  Thanks again any help

**Edit**

After talking talking in the jQuery irc it looks like it my be a bug!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented in the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278511/jquery-deferred-call-back-oddness/7278633#7278633) but the problem is your url: it has two `?` and it shouldn't

```
url = "http://otter.topsy.com/hjhkl/sehjkhhkjhkarch.js?callback=?&apikey=38A260E9D12A4908B1AF9184B691131&q=justin+bieber&window=d";
```

Should be

```
url = "http://otter.topsy.com/hjhkl/sehjkhhkjhkarch.js?callback=somevalue&apikey=38A260E9D12A4908B1AF9184B691131&q=justin+bieber&window=d";
```

or even:

```
url = "http://otter.topsy.com/hjhkl/sehjkhhkjhkarch.js"
$.getJSON(url, {
    "callback": "somevalue",
    "apikey": "38A260E9D12A4908B1AF9184B691131",
    "q": "justin bieber",
    "window": "d"
}, function(data){ alert("Got: " + data);});
```

You could url encode the `?` to `%3F` or use the second version and jQuery will url encode it for you.

**UPDATE:-** so i tested this on a view that returned a plain 500 internal server error. It worked fine: error callback ran fine.

Your url returns a 500 and a custom 500 error page.  is there anyway to turn this off and try it again?

Comment: The ? for the callback is a jQuery trick, $.getJSON notices that there is a 'callback=?' and turns that ? into a random generated jQuery function that then is used as the call back take a look at your console for xhr requests the 500 comes from this http://otter.topsy.com/hjhkl/sehjkhhkjhkarch.js?callback=jQuery162012508355733007193_1314973120028&apikey=38A260E9D12A4908B1AF9184B691131&q=justin+bieber&window=d&_=1314973120044  URL which has that 'callback=?' has been changed

Comment: @austinbv Ok so I played aroound with it and eventually i found that if the server returns a 500 error and retruns a custom 500 error page it doesn't work. Must be a jquery bug. Read my update though.